# Flyway Ant tries to open .sql file as a zip, fails with ZipException

Tags: ant, flyway

I am trying to use Flyway in my Ant project to run DDL scripts. I managed to configure the classpath so that Flyway sees the migration scripts. When I run the flyway:migrate task, I get this exception:

```
Unable to obtain resource from (...)/src/ddl/V1__create_tables_logging.sql: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
[flyway:migrate] Unable to obtain resource from (...)/src/ddl/V1__create_tables_logging.sql: 
[flyway:migrate] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

There is a suggestion at the end:

```
[flyway:migrate] Possible solution: run the Ant javac and copy tasks first so Flyway can find the migrations
```

But my project is not a Java application, I have no java sources to be compiled with javac. Does Flyway need to have the migration scripts packed in a jar? Can't it simply run some text files with SQL statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you didn't provide a configuration you have, without it it's hard to tell, what exactly causes this issue.

But it seems odd to me, that you are not using `location` property of the task, but `classpath`. Try to specify the directory with you migration scripts as follows:

```
<flyway:migrate>
    <locations>
        <location path="path/to/migrations"/>
    </locations>
    ...
</flyway:migrate>
```

Comment: The documentation is misleading, it says the migrations should be on the classpath, but that only works if you compile them to jars beforehand. What worked for me is to use the flyway.locations property and prepending the path with "filesystem:", as one of the examples in the documentation shows.